# Java OIS stuck on readObject.. how to unblock?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client and server

Server - delivers cookies

Client(s) - requests cookies then prints them once delivered.

I know OIS is blocked until outputstream is writtened and flushed, but I'm not sure what that means? I tried calling flush() after writing the request, but that didn't work.

It's getting stuck after the second time OIS#readObject is called.

Here is my code:

```
public class CookieServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch(IOException e) {

    }

    while(true) {
        try(
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        ) {
            Object inObject;
            while((inObject = in.readObject()) != null) {
                if(inObject instanceof String) {
                    if (((String) inObject).equalsIgnoreCase("Give Me Two Random Cookies")) {
                        out.writeObject(new Cookie("Chocalate Chip"));
                        out.flush();
                        out.writeObject(new Cookie("blueberry Chip"));
                        out.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        sleep(1000);
    }
}


private static void sleep(long amount) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(amount);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class CookeClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(true) {

        try (Socket echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream())) {

            out.writeObject("Give Me Two Random Cookies");

            Object inObject;
            while((inObject = in.readObject()) != null) { // gets stuck here...
                if(inObject instanceof Cookie) {
                    System.out.println("Received a: " + ((Cookie) inObject).getName() + "cookie");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        sleep(100);
    }
}


private static void sleep(long amount) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(amount);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Cookie implements Serializable{

private String name;
public Cookie(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Please help me out as I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a loop when you are only expecting two responses. That doesn't make sense. Just call `readObject()` twice.

NB Your loops are incorrect anyway. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream. It throws `EOFException`. It is therefore incorrect to use null as a loop termination condition. It can return null any time you wrote a null.

It also doesn't return null when there is no data available. It blocks.

Comment: it's not stuck in an infinite loop. in.readobject is a blocked method... I put a system.out.println to see if it was, and it wasn't printing the dummy print constantly.

Comment: You have misunderstood. I said that your loop was incorrectly written, and that looping when you're only expecting two objects doesn't make sense. The third read will block while data is not available and the connection remains open. If that isn't what you want, don't issue a third read.

Comment: I see, that was just one case. Let's say I don't know how many objects i'm receiving, what should I do? If i call readObject again (wont throw EOF since it gets blocked)

Comment: You need to either read until end of stream, as you are already doing, or send a count of the number of objects ahead of the objects.

Comment: I just got the idea to send an object to client (at the very end) "No more objects", then the client would loop through all of them and the very last object returned will be that. This will signifiy for me to break out of the loop / close the socket. What do you think of that idea.

Comment: or is there a better way?

Comment: It's completely pointless. `EOFException` already tells you exactly the same thing for nothing, whatbIm

Comment: In that case your 'no more objects' message will never arrive either. Or else you aren't closing the connection, which makes that message redundant.